# How do you align string containing accents in nim

Tags: nim-lang

In Nim, how do you align strings containing accented characters?

For example the following code

```
var maxLen = 20
var s1 = alignLeft("John le Carré", maxLen)
var s2 = alignLeft("John le Carre", maxLen)
echo s1 & ":"
echo s2 & ":"
```

produces the following output.

```
John le Carré      :
John le Carre       :
```

What is the correct way of getting the colons to line up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out the most important line:

```
import strutils
```

Which you should change to:

```
import unicode
```